# iOS container view in android

Tags: android, ios

I'm a newbie to android development. I am looking to make an app I already have out on ios for android and am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction as to where I start and what I need. My iPhone app has an initial menu screen with 8 buttons, one links to tableview with search function with detail view attached to both table and results. I then have 4 buttons linking to a container view with swipeable detail view from these and then two buttons linking to web view and the final one to another menu with call, email, directions functions.

Any pointers on where to start, help or sample code would be much appreciated

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

This website a a good place to start.

http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

You will need to download an IDE.  Eclipse is the typical free IDE that most Android devs use.  I recommend downloading Eclipse Classic, but there are great reasons to choose some of the other flavors.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

That first link has tons of resources, including sample code.